# Bash Script Run via Maven Does Not Promt for Input Properly

Tags: bash, git, maven, maven-plugin, git-bash

I have a bash script in which I am cloning a total of 5 repositories from a private server. I don't want the user to enter his credentials again and again, hence I prompt for them once and then reuse them.

This is my code for credentials promt

```
read -p "Enter Username: " username 
echo -n "Enter Password: "
read -s password
```

However when this piece of code is run via maven, it does not display the prompt messages such as `Enter Username` and does not even accept the `-s silent input` flag.
If run without maven, this script runs fine.

The catch is that if I use the `read` command without any flags or string prompts, it runs fine, which makes me think that maven might not be either recognizing or accepting these flags.

Has anyone else come across this?
I have tried using the `interactive` mode in maven as well, same results.

Comment: Why would you want to clone a repository like this?

Comment: Use either a git credentials manager or ssh.  They solve the same problems in a standard way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+skip+password

Comment: Can't use SSH as there are multiple users who clone these repositories as well. Can't keep adding new keys all the time.

Comment: That's only for your own access. Each user has it's own key. ?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use any interactivity inside build tools. All values should be injected, provided into the builds. It's not a build tool job to prompt user for them. In Maven you can use Java System properties or environment variables:

*pom.xml*

```
<user>${sysprop.user}</user>
<password>${env.PASSWORD}</user>
```

*bash*

```
export PASSWORD=s3cr3t mvn task -Dsysprop.user=root
```

Answering your question directly: make sure that the place where you run bash script (external process) links input and output stream of that external process and the Maven's JVM process. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirect-input)

Comment: I read your links, so it is possible that the behavior of bash might vary depending on whose calling it?

Comment: It's not bash's fault.

Comment: yeah you're right, I ended up taking the script out of the maven anyway